# jQuery how to constantly check if element is hidden/visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hidden, visible

I have a couple of HTML5 videos on my website (within a slider), they automatically cycle every x seconds (or when user clicks "next slide").

I want to stop the videos that are actually invisible to user, any ideas how to achieve that?

I was tryng to do something like that, but I guess there's "each" missing and it works after click instead all the time (ok, in fact it doesn't work because "this" is used wrong here I guess, but you get the point, sorry, I'm not a JS-guy at all :():

```
document.on('click', ".videojs:hidden", function(){
   alert('video hidden!');    
   jQuery(this).player.pause();
});
```

Comment: do you have only one video or more?

Comment: @DRP96, I have unlimited number of them, from 5 to "a lot" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into this:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Sep/12/jQuery-CSS-Property-Monitoring-Plugin-updated

You can then do something like this:

```
jQuery(".videojs").watch("display,visibility", function() { 
  if(!jQuery(".videojs").is(':visible'))
  {
    alert('video hidden!');    
    jQuery(".videojs").player.pause();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to look into using [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). Something like:

```
var videoInterval = setInterval(function() {
  // video check logic here
}, 1000);
```

The above code will run your video check every second (1000 milliseconds). You can probably also use `$(` instead of `jQuery(`. The `videoInterval` variable will let you use `clearInterval()` if you need to stop the "loop" of checks for any reason. I believe this code will need to be inside of your `$(document).ready(function() {...})` block.

Comment: I can't, the cycle time can be changed + what when user decides to cycle manually?

Comment: You can clear the interval and set a new one to change the timer. You can also clear the interval and start it again when a user cycles manually. Your other option is to hook into your cycling logic (if you're using a plugin, most provide a callback function that is called when the plugin cycles) and turn off the hidden movie(s) then.